# How to accept data in ModelForm and display data from DB in same webpage

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to have a ModelForm that accepts user input and on the same webpage, also display all the records in the database. I created one view with a ModelForm called views.users and another view that displays all the users from the database called views.display_users. How do I put these both in my urls.py file? My urls.py code is below. Thank you!

```
# urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app3 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/',views.users,name='users'),
    path('users/',views.display_users,name='display_users'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate `django-restframework` [link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework). This is one of the most popular django third party app to use in project. Django restframework provide viewset, where you can `retrive`, `post`, `put`, `delete`, `list` and also add many custom action in same end-point. Viewset tutorial [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/).